Error for mitosheet only when run in streamlit
I am trying to use the mitosheet python package with streamlit. I have installed mitosheet to my virtual environment by "pip install mitosheet".
I only have the following few lines of code in flight_schedule.py:
import streamlit as st
from mitosheet.streamlit.v1 import spreadsheet

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
st.title('Tesla Stock Volume Analysis')
print("Hello World!")

When I run it in anaconda prompt with the command "python flight_schedule.py", I get the expected output:
2024-06-28 10:12:24.809
  Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
  command:

    streamlit run flight_schedule.py [ARGUMENTS]
Hello World!

However, when I try to run it in streamlit, by entering "streamlit run flight_schedule.py" into anaconda prompt, I get the error:
  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://10.42.16.117:8501

2024-06-28 10:13:27.387 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sstokke\.conda\envs\PhenoCrop\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 589, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "\\file-1-01.nmbu.no\project\PhenoCrop\Test_Folder\Test_SINDRE\flight_schedule.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mitosheet.streamlit.v1 import spreadsheet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mitosheet'

I find this very strange, and I have not been able to find anyone with the same issue by googling.
My installed version of mitosheet is 0.1.576 and my installed version of python is 3.8.19.
I have tried to switch virtual environment to some other and back to see if that would solve it.

I found out that it works if I run it with this command instead: "python -m streamlit run flight_schedule.py". I have no idea of why.
